# Minimal order of a group with a particular property

Tags: group-theory

I fix an integer $n$. I am looking for a group $G$ for which there exist elements $g_1, \dots, g_n \in G$ and $h_1, \dots, h_n \in G$ such that
$$ h_kg_k^{-1} \neq h_j g_i^{-1}$$
as long as $\mathrm{Card}\, \{i,j,k\} \geq 2$.

My question is: what is the minimal order of such a group ?

The only thing I have $\mathrm{Card}\, G \geq 2n-1$. Indeed, taking $i=k$ and $j \neq k$, we see that the $g_1, \dots, g_n$ are pairwise distinct. Similarly, the $h_1, \dots, h_n$ are pairwise distinct. We can always reduce to the case where $g_1 = h_1 = e$ (the neutral element). And choosing $k = 1$ and $i, j \neq 1$ we see that $\{h_2, \dots, h_n\}$ and $\{g_2, \dots, g_n\}$ are disjoint.

For those who are curious, this question is related to the design of error-correcting codes.

I am no expert in group theory, but maybe this question will ring a bell for group theorists.

Comment: Please proofread this more carefully. ${\rm Card}(\{i,j,h\}) \le 2$ doesn't make sense. Also taking $i=j=k$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: Are you designing LDPC codes by any chance? I once faced a similar problem when designing low-density lattice codes. A condition like this (don't remember exactly) was needed to use a group giving rise to a Tanner graph free of 4-cycles. I added another one to get rid of 6-cycles as well. IIRC I found sets of something like 8 elements within $S_7$ (size 5040). I was aiming a bit higher (the equations for cycles of length 6 had more degrees of freedom) so it was not unexpected that it was more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I have not enough reputation points to add a comment nor to reedit my question. As Derek Holt pointed out, there is a mistake, the condition is clearly $\mathrm{Card}\, \{i,j,k\} \geq 2$, *i.e* at least two indices are distinct.

Comment: I didn't realize you couldn't even edit your question! I have edited it, and I will assume it is correct unless you answer again.

Comment: @vizietto: It looks like you may have lost your login credentials, because you are answering using a different account that asked this question (which would explain why you cannot edit). Read [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) from our help page to fix things.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : you are right. The above inequalities express that the girth of the Tanner graph is larger than 8.